# python read lines of website source code 100 lines at a time

Tags: python, url, urllib, readline

I'm trying to read the source code from a website 100 lines at a time

For example:

```
self.code = urllib.request.urlopen(uri)

#Get 100 first lines
self.lines = self.getLines()

...

#Get 100 next lines
self.lines = self.getLines()
```

My getLines code is like this:

```
def getLines(self):
    res = []
    i = 0

    while i < 100:
        res.append(str(self.code.readline()))
        i+=1

return res
```

But the problem is that `getLines()` always returns the first 100 lines of the code.

I've seen some solutions with `next()` or `tell()` and `seek()`, but it seems that those functions are not implemented in HTTPResponse class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) `urllib.request.urlopen(uri)` returns a file like object, so you should be able to do:

```
from itertools import islice

def getLines(self)
    res = []
    for line in islice(self.code,100): 
        res.append(line)
    return res
```

there's more information on `islice` in the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). Using iterators will avoid the `while` loop and manual increments.

If you absolutely must use `readline()`, it's advisable to use a `for` loop, i.e.

```
for i in xrange(100): 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib

def getLines(code):
    res = []
    i = 0

    while i < 100:
        res.append(str(code.readline()))
        i+=1

    return res

uri='http://www.google.com/'
code = urllib.urlopen(uri)

#Get 100 first lines
lines = getLines(code)

print lines

#Get 100 next lines
lines = getLines(code)

print lines
```